# Redirect error with trailing slash in URL

Tags: php, apache, permalinks

In my website URL, when the last slash is removed, it works fine. However, when I do not remove it, it gives a redirect error.

The URL is like this:

```
https://example.com/test/2018/
```

This causes a redirect error, but when the last slash is removed,

```
https://example.com/test/2018
```

it works fine. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you add details about how you're serving the website? Generally speaking, that behavior is expected.

Comment: What kind of webserver do you use (Apache httpd, Tomcat, Nginx, Node.js, ...)? Please add your configuration.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about your stack?

Comment: I am using apache 2.4 and php version is 7.3 on my local host server it works fine but on live server the last slash create issue but if i manually removed, then it loads fine, i change permalinks also but it do not effect it

Comment: Fixing grammar, tags, and title

Comment: Try to avoid trailing slashes - the servers are usually smart enough to add it themselves, if needed.